# What other reason can there be for unrecognized RAM memory?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a [Lenovo G50-70 laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/g-series/g50-70/). The specs say that supports up to 8GB PC3-12800 DDR3L SDRAM 1600 MHz. I bought it with 4GB of RAM and I want to add extra 4GB.

I bought one 4GB RAM stick from Crucial, with similar specs of the one built in, but it my computer won't detect.

- Memory is not recognized neither by Windows or BIOS
- BIOS is up to date
- Running Win10 64bit
- It's not a connection issue (I tried multiple times)
- The motherboard has 2 slots. I tried switching places, but it never detects the new memory
- If I leave only the new memory, computer won't boot
- I tried also with a new Crucial RAM memory of 2GB, and the behavior was always the same as the one of 4GB (thus I don't expect that is a faulty memory)

Here's a picture of the memory sticks I have now. The Crucial is the new one; the Samsung is the one that came with the laptop.

[image]

Comment: Either its a bad stick or it is not compatible with that motherboard.

Comment: Your machine uses 1600MHz memory. That new stick is 1066MHz. Sometimes laptops are very specific about which memory modules and frequencies they will accept. I suspect this is the issue.

Comment: @SamForbis I thought that as long as you'd not exceed a max limit, having a lower frequency memory would not have compatibility issues

Answer (score 1):

The Crucial site lists two options for two models of the Lenovo G50-70:

- The mobile version :
  [Lenovo G50-70m](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/lenovo-g50-70m),
  which uses RAM of type DDR3L.
- The non-mobile version :
  [Lenovo G50-70](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/lenovo-g50-70),
  which uses RAM of type DDR3.

Your existing and working RAM is
[Samsung M471B5173EB0-YK0](https://memory.net/product/m471b5173eb0-yk0-samsung-1x-4gb-ddr3-1600-sodimm-pc3l-12800s-single-rank-x8-module/),
which is of type DDR3. But the Crucial RAM you bought is of type DDR3L,
which is then incompatible with your computer.

I suggest getting in touch with Crucial and asking for a replacement.
Note that Crucial supplies a Scan Computer utility, with which you cannot
go wrong, and I would suggest verifying with this utility the RAM you need
before getting in touch with Crucial.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and links. I understand that ddr3L ram would work in ddr3 devices (but not the other way around). I am wrong?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, this depends on the motherboard and power supply.

Comment: Actually, the Samsung memory is DDR3L. It is not written explicitly in the specs (in the link you sent), but it says that it's low voltage and it specifies that it works under 1.35 V. Thus, it is also DDR3L, as the Crucial RAM. This does not mean that there is not a reason why the Crucial memory is not compatible with the motherboard, but such "reason" it's still unclear to me.

Comment: Many RAM sticks are supposed to adapt automatically to DDR3/L, but again, motherboard may be incompatible. I'm curious about the RAM that is found for you by the Crucial Scan Computer utility.